# An inequality about hypergeometric function(1F2).

Tags: inequality, asymptotics, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

**I'm trying to prove the following inequality:**

For $x \in (0,3)$, $$ {_1F_2[1;\frac{5}{4},\frac{7}{4};\frac{-(1\cdot x)^2}{4}]}+{_1F_2[1;\frac{5}{4},\frac{7}{4};\frac{-(3\cdot x)^2}{4}]}\gt 2\cdot {_1F_2[1;\frac{5}{4},\frac{7}{4};\frac{-(5\cdot x)^2}{4}]}$$

**My attempts:**

I wrote [Fresnel Integral Transform](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FunctionExpand%5BHypergeometricPFQ%5B%7B1%7D,%7B5%2F4,7%2F4%7D,-x%5E2%2F4%5D%5D) for Hypergeometric Functions, but it gaves me only more complicated formula to prove.

I also find some [Series representations](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F2/06/ShowAll.html) for Hypergeometric Functions. But I then tried unsuccessfully to express it and didn't find a good one to re-express it.

I also searched L.Luke's book trying to use asymptote to show it but I didn't find a good approximation. Perhaps the hypergeom can simplify with the Bessel function?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can be brute-forced by using the same approach as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2677960).

The left-hand side of the inequality will have to be expanded to order 16, and the right-hand side to order 34; the approximation errors will be bounded by the absolute values of the $x^{18}$ and the $x^{36}$ terms respectively.

Then, since everything is polynomial, a Sturm sequence can be computed to prove that the difference of the lower bound for the left-hand side and the upper bound for the right-hand side does not have zeros on $(0,3]$.

Comment: Thank you! Why we expand the inequality to order 16 and 34 on the LHS and RHS respectively?

Comment: Simply because the experimentation shows that a lesser number of terms is not enough. The lower bound for the lhs diverges very fast to $-\infty$ when $x$ grows, and the upper bound for the rhs to $+\infty$. Approximations of lower orders would intersect before $x=3$.