# Hypergeometric Functions (2F1) positive everywhere

Tags: hypergeometric-function

Five years ago, there was [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2677241/to-show-hypergeometric-functions1f2-positive) about the positivity of the hypergeometric functions $_{1}F_{2}$ on a short interval $(0,5)$. I would like to ask a very similar question but for the hypergeometric functions $_{2}F_{1}$ on the whole line. The question is

whether or not the following
$$_2F_1\Big[\frac{3}{2}, \frac{3}{2}; 2 ;- x^2 \Big] > 0 \quad \text{for all } x>0$$
holds.

Via Maple, plotted on the interval $[0,20]$, it seems that the answer is affirmative, see the picture below, as the function decays to zero.

[image]

I tried with [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Hypergeometric2F1%5B3%2F2%2C%203%2F2%2C2%2C%20-x%5E2%5D%20), please take a look.

Comment: Your function is $$
\frac{2}{\pi }\int_0^1 {\sqrt {\frac{t}{{1 - t}}} \frac{{{\rm d}t}}{{(1 + x^2 t)^{3/2} }}} 
$$ by [$(15.6.1)$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.6.E1).

Comment: Wow @@ thanks for a useful comment.